# How to retrieve all or matching email addresses from a mail server using java mail API?

Tags: email, jakarta-mail, email-client, mail-server

I am trying to implement a feature in the email client that we are developing to find the list of email addresses in a particular domain, once the end user keys in the first 3 letters in to/cc/bcc box. Since the mails will be sent only to one predefined domain (which is internal).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In general, there's no way to find all the valid email addresses in a domain.  And even in cases where it is possible, there's no standard way to do it.  JavaMail isn't going to help you here.  If your mail server supports such a capability, you're going to need to figure out how to do it in a product-specific way.